# How to time server responses with Sinon.JS?

Tags: javascript, mocking, jasmine, integration-testing, sinon

I want to test how my web application deals with server responses. That's why I created a test scenario which uses [Sinon.JS to fake a server](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer).

My application code makes two requests and in my test scenario I want to force the situation that the response to the first request is sent **after** the response to my second request.

**Sequence:**

1. Request 1
2. Request 2
3. Response 2
4. Response 1

Here is the CoffeeScript code that I wrote for my test case:

```
# Request 1
server.respondWith 'GET', "http://localhost/endpoint", [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, '{"A":"A"}']
# Request 2
server.respondWith 'GET', "http://localhost/endpoint", [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, '{"B":"B"}']

# My application code
...

# Response 1
server.respond()

# Response 2
server.respond()
```

Once I start the test all REST calls to `http://localhost/endpoint` from my application code get the same response (`{"B":"B"}`). So to me it looks like Sinon.JS takes always the response from the last URL mapping which has been defined using `respondWith`.

But I want my faked server to return `{"B":"B"}` to the first hit on `http://localhost/endpoint`. On the second hit it should return `{"A":"A"}`.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
# Request 1
request_1 = server.respondWith 'GET', "http://localhost/endpoint", [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, '{"A":"A"}']
# Request 2
request_2 = server.respondWith 'GET', "http://localhost/endpoint", [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, '{"B":"B"}']

# My application code (makes multiple requests to the same endpoint)
...

# Response 1
request_2.respond()

# Response 2
request_1.respond()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Jasmine-AJAX](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax) lib made by Pivotal for this.

CoffeeScript:

```
it 'can handle an unlimited amount of requests and respond to each one individually after all requests have been made', ->
    jasmine.Ajax.install() # put this in beforeEach
    url = 'http://localhost/test'

    $.ajax
            dataType: 'json'
            url: url
            success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
                    # Receives {"A":"A"}
                    console.log "Response: #{JSON.stringify(data)}"

    $.ajax
            dataType: 'json'
            url: url
            success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
                    # Receives {"B":"B"}
                    console.log "Response: #{JSON.stringify(data)}"

    responses = [
            {
                    contentType: 'application/json'
                    responseText: '{"A":"A"}'
                    status: 200
            },
            {
                    contentType: 'application/json'
                    responseText: '{"B":"B"}'
                    status: 200
            }
    ]

    for i in [0...jasmine.Ajax.requests.count()]
            request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.at i
            request.respondWith responses[i]

    expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.count()).toBe 2
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall() # put this in afterEach
```

With `count()` and `at()` you can get all requests ordered by time and put them in an array where you can for example shift the requests and respond to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0

$.mockjax(
  function(requestSettings){
    if(requestSettings.url === "path/to/api" && requestSettings.type === "POST"){

      return {
        response: function(origSettings){
          if (count == 0){
            this.responseText = {msg:"this is first response" }
            this.status = 200
          }
          else if(count == 1){
            //more combos
          }
          else{
            this.responseText = {msg:"this is last response" }
            this.status = 200
          }
          count = (count + 1) % 4
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```